# Symfony2: How to disable profiler entirely?

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

Even if i remove from all config*.yml files `web_profiler`... I'm getting

```
RuntimeException: You need to enable either the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension for the profiler to run properly.
```

I just dont want to install sqlite on my system and i can't find how to turn off profiler entirely...

Any tips?

**UPD**: Commented in FrameworkExtension.php

```
if (isset($config['profiler'])) {
    $this->registerProfilerConfiguration($config['profiler'], $container, $loader);
}
```

But that's not good solution

Comment: you could also install php sqlite extension..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your app/AppKernel.php.

Removing the line

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
```

should do the trick! Now the bundle never gets loaded and therefore now SQLite2 database is needed.

Comment: don't forget to remove the profiler configuration in app_dev.yml, otherwise you will get an error page

Answer (score 7):

Or you can change in your config_dev.yml:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
```